# Random background image selection for banner using javascript and css for 2 instances

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate random image selections for the background images for my banner using javascript and css to style it.

I'm using IDs to select the images (`#background` for browsers and `#background-sm` for mobile).

I have it working for browsers but I need to add a separate instance for mobile use. I've added this to the bottom of my home page but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right?

Thanks for any help!

```html
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    if (document.getElementById) { window.onload = swap };
        function swap() 
    {
            var numimages=4;
            rndimg = new Array(
                "img/hero-home-01.jpg", 
                "img/hero-home-02.jpg", 
                "img/hero-home-03.jpg", 
                "img/hero-home-04.jpg");
            x=(Math.floor(Math.random()*numimages));
            randomimage=(rndimg[x]);
            document.getElementById("banner").style.backgroundImage = "url("+ randomimage +")";
        }
        {
            var numimages=4;
            rndimg = new Array(
                "img/hero-home-sm-01.jpg", 
                "img/hero-home-sm-02.jpg", 
                "img/hero-home-sm-03.jpg", 
                "img/hero-home-sm-04.jpg");
            x=(Math.floor(Math.random()*numimages));
            randomimage=(rndimg[x]);
            document.getElementById("banner-sm").style.backgroundImage = "url("+ randomimage +")";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Are there any issues?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the code. It wasn't working when I added them as separate scripts. I'm just not sure if I'm doing this right or if there is a better way to add 2 instances of javascript to a page? I've got it working on the browser now but I can't seem to get site access to test for mobile.

Comment: I've updated my answer, take a look @Elarie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the second `swap` declaration overrides the first one.

```js
function a() {
  console.log('a');
}

function a() {
  console.log('b');
}

a();
```

You can declare `swap` once and:

First option is to run both of the rotations in there.

Something like:

```js
function swap() {
  const rndimg = [
    "img/hero-home-01.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-02.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-03.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-04.jpg"
  ];
  const mobileRndimg = [
    "img/hero-home-sm-01.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-sm-02.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-sm-03.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-sm-04.jpg"
  ];
  const x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * rndimg.length));
  const randomimage = rndimg[x];
  const randomimageMobile = mobileRndimg[x];
  document.getElementById("banner").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + randomimage + ")";
  document.getElementById("banner-sm").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + randomimageMobile + ")";
}
```

Second option, you can check if the device is desktop or mobile and declare the images array based on that

```js
function swap() {
  const rndimg = isMobile ? [
    "img/hero-home-sm-01.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-sm-02.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-sm-03.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-sm-04.jpg"
  ] : [
    "img/hero-home-01.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-02.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-03.jpg",
    "img/hero-home-04.jpg"
  ];
  const elementId = isMobile ? 'banner-sm' : 'banner';
  const x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * rndimg.length));
  const randomimage = rndimg[x];
  document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundImage = "url(" + randomimage + ")";
}

// https://dev.to/timhuang/a-simple-way-to-detect-if-browser-is-on-a-mobile-device-with-javascript-44j3
function isMobile() {
  return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
}
```

And, if `#banner` is just next to `#banner-sm` and you show only one of them (using media query), you can have only `#banner`. Only the images path will be different.

Comment: Hmm, that's not working. I tried option 1 (the css is driving the image selection so I don't know if option 2 will mess it up). Images are not loading. Do I need to add an image variable (ie: do I need to list the number of images available for selection)?

Comment: Hi Mosh Feu, any suggestions as to why the first option isn't working?

Comment: Any errors in the console? It's pretty hard to answer without seeing the whole code, can you create a working example (jsbin, jsfiddle etc.)?

Comment: @Elarie what do you think?

Comment: here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j7h3o9eq/
I can't get it to work here either. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to call the function `swap()`. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/azj0s6q2/

Comment: Yup, that did it!! Woo hoo! Thanks so much. That last bit was missing from the code above (if you want to update it for others.) Thanks so much!!

Comment: Glad to hear :)